# Simple Marginalization Explanation Please

Tags: probability, bayes, bayesian-network

I am having difficulty understanding this marginalization.

Let's say you have this relationship $p(a,b,c) = p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)$

From that you are trying to get $p(a,b)$

$p(a,b) = p(a) \sum\limits_{c} p(c|a)p(b|c) = p(a)p(b|a)$

Can you explain how you can go from that sum to the last step? It doesn't seem to make sense. For example, $\sum\limits_c p(c|a) = 1$, right? Therefore the only term you are considering is $p(b|c)$. How does summing over $p(b|c)$ give me $p(b|a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $B$ is independent from $A$ given $C$, i.e.,
$$p(b|a,c)=p(b|c)$$ since
$$p(b|a,c)\propto p(a,b,c)=p(b|c)p(c|a)p(a)\propto p(b|c)$$
which does not depend on $A=a$, but not once $C$ is integrated out:
$$p(b|a)=\sum_c p(b,c|a)=\sum_c p(b|c)p(c|a)$$
And when you state that
$$\sum_c p(b|c)p(c|a)=\sum_c p(b|c)$$
because
$$\sum_c p(b|c)p(c|a)=1$$
***this is incorrect***.

Comment: OK, I think this makes sense, but how did you know that the random variable B was independent from A given C. Where did that come from?

Comment: @AmyStevens: see my update.